# how to retrive data from solr. i have a item that holds the list product model.how to get the data from controller

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

i indexed the item into solr. in that item I stored a list of product models in a column. i dont know how to retrive that data from solr. what i want is steps to get that data from solr. like from controller to solr how can achieve it

```
<collectiontypes>
        <collectiontype code="topsellingproductscodes" elementtype="Product" autocreate="true" type="list"/>
    </collectiontypes>
<itemtype code="TopSoldProducts">
            <deployment table="TopSoldProducts" typecode="23677"/>
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="products" type="topsellingproductscodes">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
used this impex to indexed the data into solr:

    
 $siteUid=apparel-uk
 $catalogVersions=catalogVersions(catalog(id),version);
 $productCatalog=apparelProductCatalog
 $serverConfigName=$siteUid SolrServerConfig
 $indexConfigName=$siteUid SolrIndexConfig
 $searchConfigName=$siteUid PageSize
 $facetSearchConfigName=$siteUid 
 $facetSearchConfigDescription=top selling products solr index
 $searchIndexNamePrefix=topsellingproductscodes
 $solrIndexedType=$siteUid-TopSellingProducts
 $indexBaseSite=$siteUid
 $indexLanguages=en
 $indexCurrencies=GBP
 $lang=en
 
 # Declare the indexed type MyEmployee
 INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedType;identifier[unique=true];type(code);variant
 ;$solrIndexedType;TopSoldProducts;false
 
 #Adding top Selling Products into facet search config
 INSERT_UPDATE SolrFacetSearchConfig;name[unique=true]       ;description                     ;indexNamePrefix        ;languages(isocode);currencies(isocode);solrServerConfig(name);solrSearchConfig(description);solrIndexConfig(name);solrIndexedTypes(identifier);enabledLanguageFallbackMechanism;$catalogVersions;;;;;;;;;
                                    ;$facetSearchConfigName;$facetSearchConfigDescription;$searchIndexNamePrefix;$indexLanguages  ;$indexCurrencies ;Default        ;Default;Default;$solrIndexedType;true;$productCatalog:Online;;;;;;;;;
 
 # Create the queries that will be used to extract data for Solr
 INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexerQuery;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];identifier[unique=true];type(code);injectCurrentDate[default=true];injectCurrentTime[default=true];injectLastIndexTime[default=true];query;user(uid) 
 ;$solrIndexedType;$solrIndexedType-fullQuery;full;;;false;"select {pk} from {topSoldProducts}";anonymous
 ;$solrIndexedType;$solrIndexedType-updateQuery;update;;;;"select {tsp.pk} from {topSoldProducts as tsp} where {modifiedtime}>=?lastIndexTime";anonymous                    

INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code)   ;sortableType(code);localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=false];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority  ;visible        ;fieldValueProvider            ;includeInResponse[default=true];backofficeDisplayName
                                 ;$solrIndexedType                        ;products         ;string       ;                  ;                        ;true                          ;                        ;                  ;Custom           ;1000         ;true            ;topSoldProductsValueProvider ;                                  ;topSoldProducts Prefix
```

after this i did a full indexing the products are comming in solr.
how can retrive this data from solr.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail to this question in order for people to help you. Here are some ideas on how to ask a good question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In your case it might be helpful to see what the document that you are storing in Solr looks like and what kind of query you are issuing to retrieve the information.

Comment: @HectorCorrea hai i edited my question .  please let me knoe if you have any idea about how to get data from Solr. thank you.